# Google Maps error on showing

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

Some code to display google maps v2 I wrote was working fine last year, it now doesn't. The only thing I can see that's different is I've updated the SDK which has brought down a new version of Google Play Services.

The error is 'error inflating' the following, and it fails on every device I've tried:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/worldmap"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

It errors within the OnCreateView event as soon as it tries to load the layout.

However, nothing has changed in code. My manifest is like for the relevant bits:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" 
        android:value="MY KEY"/>
```

I have added the .\sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib as a project and linked it to my project which I did via project properties/Androidlibrary section.

The only thing I can see in my Console output is the following line:

```
[2014-05-12 13:19:59 - AndroidAC_Session08a] Installing AndroidAC_Session08a.apk...
[2014-05-12 13:20:10 - AndroidAC_Session08a] Success!
[2014-05-12 13:20:10 - google-play-services_lib] Could not find google-play-services_lib.apk!
```

Comment: do you see a green tick when you reference the library project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this piece of lines in the manifest and check,

```
 <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it. I don't care, last year I copied the code from Vogella website on his Maps tutorial and normally everything is just fine with what he writes :)

Answer (score 0):

Using the new Google Play Services

Steps:

1) remove the google_play_services-lib reference from the Java build path

2)  add the library reference in Properties | Android | Library references

Comment: that's how I did it. See @madhu answer